# After prompt is closed on forms, a stuck "Working..." toast at the bottom left appears

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I created a simple forms apps script app that lets you attach a calendar event to a form and be able to send it to respondents. The problem I am having is that when I prompt the script user for a simple text, after the prompt is done (also applies to `ui.alert()`), a toast pops at the bottom left of the form and stays there until another prompt comes up, and does the same thing.

[image: a toast stuck at Working...]

Here is the code for the prompt:

```js
function promptUser(message) {
  // Display a dialog box with a message, input field, and an "OK" button. The user can also
  // close the dialog by clicking the close button in its title bar.
  let ui = FormApp.getUi();

  let response = ui.prompt(message, ui.ButtonSet.OK);

  // Process the user's response.
  if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
    return response.getResponseText();
  } else if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

and I do use this inside of the HTML sidebar using the `google.script.run`.

What exactly triggers this and how would I get rid of this toast. I have tried using an `alert`, which does the same exact thing. The only other solution would be to use the `ModalDialogue`, which means I have to go through the tedious process of creating the HTML and handle the input myself.

Comment: can you share your HTML code a well, so that the community will have better understanding of your over all projects and have a greater chance of this questions being answered

Comment: Well, I have created a new project to test the consistency of the issue, and it seems like it persists, even on a fresh form apps script. I isolated it, without any additional API calls, no use of HTML, just bare bones `Code.gs` with the `FormApp.getUI().alert()` and it still does the same exact thing.

Comment: I did replicate this on my end and the working native loading notifcation from my end doesn't show. Can you share your test project here as well so I can take a look at it and have better understanding where it is coming I might have replicated incorrectly due to shortage of information. Thank you for responding

Comment: Please try to replicate this as well using a Google Chrome instead of Microsoft Edge.

Comment: I have tried using different browsers, and the loading notification consistently appears and stay there. I tested this in Chrome, Edge, and even my phone's Chrome and Firefox. I tried using different accounts, I'm so confused. Anyways, here is a link to the isolated form: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1xsj0lJeqFq1ZIBV6KTCYdLHOVerdZCPlSPEbpcw-iPg/edit